# Kotlin Filter - The Expression is Unused

Tags: kotlin, filter

I have a Kotlin application that filters a collection elements in a manner similar to the following:

```
fun main() {
    val strings = arrayOf("A", "B", "C")
    val acceptAll = true
    println(
            strings.filter {
                if (acceptAll) {
                    true // "The expression is unused"
                }
                // Other filters
                false
            }
    )
}
```

However, the `true` line is highlighted by IntelliJ with the message "The expression is unused". Sure enough, my program does not hit that code path, the filter returns `false`, and I end up with an empty array.

This is a simplified example, but it illustrates what it is that I'm trying to accomplish.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To actually return the value true from the lambda inside that if statement, you have to replace `true` with `return@filter true`.

The statement `true` does not mean "return true", it only means that when evaluated, the result of the evaluation will be *true*. Only the last statement of a lambda is considered the return value. And since `true` was not the last statement, it was not returned. After evaluating `true`, execution jumped out of the `if`-case body and executed the next statement, which is `false`. Since that is also the last statement in the lambda, it was also the return value of the lambda, even though it executed the body of the `if` statement just before that.

You can leave the statement `false` without changes. Since it is the *last statement* (contrary to `true`) in the lambda, it will also be the return value from the lambda if that statement is executed. For symmetry, I would personally change it to `return@filter false`, however.

The docs on this can be found at [Returning a value from a lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#returning-a-value-from-a-lambda-expression) and [Return at Labels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels)

Comment: That worked! I'm still not completely clear on why that resolved the issue, but it did.

Comment: @AndySenn The statement `true` does not mean "return true", it only means that when evaluated, the result of the evaluation will be `true`. Only the last statement of a lambda is considered the return value. And since `true` was not the last statement, it was not returned. After evaluating `true`, execution jumped out of the `if`-case and executed the next statement, which was `false`. Since that is the last statement, it was also the return value of the lambda, even though it executed the body of the if statement just before that.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you @Enselic for the additional information!

Comment: @AndySenn I'm glad I managed to explain it! I incorporated this explanation in my answer now, to make it clearer for future visitors of this question :)